# schedule email notification alert in java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

HI, I am a final year student, working for my final year project. Now, i got the situation in my project, where i need email alert to be sent on the defined time or in other words, it will be sent on every Monday.

I search my query in google and in this website also, and found the term Quartz API. But, the problem is, i'm confuse with the API, whether it will helpful for my project, if yes, then how can i implement it. Any tutorial is available, which explain it with the screen-shots. I am very new for Quartz API, so please help me...

Help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

If your scheduling needs aren't very complex (and they don't appear to be), it will probably be a lot easier to use something like [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) instead of Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, kindly search with keyword "tutorial" appended to your search string:

http://www.javabeat.net/qna/152-quartz-job-scheduler-example-code/

http://www.roseindia.net/quartz/